# Please help with 3 way dimmer hookup with existing 2 way switches

Tags: electrical

I am replacing an old dimmer and the wire colors are different that the new ones so very confused about which wire goes where.

In the diagram shown below all whites are together. I have 3 existing loose wires 1,2 and 6 on the diagram.
Where do I connect 4,5 and 6 from the dimmer.

Wire 6 puzzles me a bit since its hooked up with a red and a black on the switch already.
My new gradator has 2 red, 1 black and ground

Thanks in advanced to all electrical savvy people willing to help :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How was it connected before?

Comment: Old dimmer had 2 black and one red wire and no ground. Also one red and black wires were coming out of the same hole of the dimmer back so realy cant use this to figure out the new layout with diff wires colors

Comment: I think you're placing far too much importance on the meaning of wire colors.  They are suggestive at best; the essential data is stored in how things are connected to each other.  Hence my question.  Also, is the other end of that lower left /3 cable, is that another 3-way switch or does it go straight to the lamp? *There's a LOT going on in this box...*

Comment: Is the middle outlet controlled by a switch from somewhere else?

Comment: What make and model is your new dimmer?

Comment: Just some precision, I just noticed my diagram is misleading. The two outlets on  the right are actually single pole switches and not outlets.The new dimmer is an EATON 3 way.

Comment: I guess the trick is understanding how the current flows in this setup. I only have 3 wires to hookup so has to be simple for anyone who knows more than me about electrical hookups.

Comment: Is there  a bundle of bare wires in the back of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This isn't so hard once you figure out what's what

From the instructions you posted, we know that the black wire on your new dimmer is  the common, and the two red wires on the dimmer are the two travelers.  Coming from the wall, we can tell that the black wire that is spliced to the wire going off to the single pole switch is the always-hot feed coming in from the fact it's connected to that single pole switch, as well as another incoming wire.  This means that we can safely hook that up to the black wire on the dimmer, and also connect the green wire on the dimmer to the grounding bundle in the box if present or land it on a ground screw in the back of the box if there's no grounds present, then connect the remaining open wires from the wall to the red wires from the dimmer since we know they're the travelers by process of elimination.

Comment: Great explanation, if I got this that means the black  wire labeled 5 on my diagram would go to wire 6 on my middle switch. As far are the two red wires remaining needing to be connected to wires 1 and 2 which are actually a red and a black wire does it matter which one goes were or any red to either of is allright ?

Comment: @Joc -- it doesn't matter all that much which red wire on the dimmer goes to which traveler, and yes, on your diagram, wire 5 from the dimmer goes to wire 6 from the other switch

Comment: @ ThreePhaseEel, all is good now and you were right :)